# Qt decimal separator

Tags: qt, qt5.5

In many (all?) Qt gui control (like QDoubleSpinBox), QDoubleValidator etc ',' using as a decimal separator. But QString method toFloat, toDouble use '.'. What is the best way to resolve this conflict for all platforms and locals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is resolved. I use QLocale().toFloat() insted QString::toFloat().

Answer (score 2):

Qt uses system locale to display numbers in widgets, which sometimes has ',' as decimal separator. You can use `QLocale::system().toDouble()` to get locale-dependent conversion.

Comment: Written at the same time:). "QLocale::system()." is equivalent to "QLocale()."?

Comment: @Bleach According to the documentation: "QLocale::QLocale(). Constructs a QLocale object initialized with the default locale. If no default locale was set using setDefault(), this locale will be the same as the one returned by system()"